# Is it possible to define a big part of xaml as a tag and use this tag in different places?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I have a big part of xaml code (ListBox & ListBoxItems) and I need to use this ListBox in different places. I'd like to define this ListBox once to use it like: `<my:SimpleListBox />` instead of copy/paste. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Just define it as a UserControl.  See a complete example here in the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. A UserControl - The regular way of encapsulating a part of the UI with a single project.
2. A Templated (or Custom) Control - The regular way of encapulating a control and making it 'Templateable' and reusable across applications
3. A string of XAML - A very uncommon way of storing a part of the UI. Use the XAML Serializer to load it.

Consider 1 first then 2 and use 3 only when messing around or when you know what you are doing.

Comment: I needed the first one. The second one I've already used, but it's not for what I needed. PS: Accepted Gambit's answer, because he has answered first.